# Is there a way in MIPS to print an integer value using syscall 4?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Say I have a value 0x000000aa stored in register $t0.

Without using syscall 1, I want to print that value out in decimal which is 170.

In python it would just be str(170), but I'm not sure where to start in mips. Any hints?

Comment: You will just have to implement `str` yourself.

Comment: print it out where and how?  could be a massive amount of work depending on the answer which I assume it is not.  how would you print the individual digits out "1", "7", "0"?

Comment: syscalls imply a system no to operating systems are assumed to use the same syscalls, what system is this what is a syscall 1 and a syscall 4?

Comment: if you are talking about MARS then you simply make the null terminated ascii string, "170" and print that  (0x31,0x37,0x30,0x00) (just like you would in python or c or any other language)

Comment: Converting an integer to a string "could be a massive amount of work" -- it's work, but massive, I think not; it might involve a short loop.  So, try it in C first, then convert to assembly.  Now, converting a floating point number to a string with accuracy -- that's complex, but fortunately, you are only working with integers.